# SQL: apply a "group by" to a query, with additional logic

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Given an employee table with fields "DeptId" and "employeeId", how can I display all the departments which have more employees than department 20? 
I would like to display the department id and number of employee in the department.

SO far I have tried this:

```
SELECT DeptId as "Dept Id", count(employeeId) as "Number of employee"
FROM EMPLOYEE 
WHERE DeptId IN
 (
   SELECT DeptId
    FROM EMPLOYEE
   GROUP BY DeptId
  )
AND DeptId <> 20
group by DeptId;
```

I can't seem to solve the part where I need to find the department which has more employees than department 20.

P.S Total newb

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Well, read the question. Then read the accepted answer. It may give you an idea.

Comment: okie.. thanks for the help, but I was hoping for a direct answer to my question.

Comment: Yes, that approach tends to solicit poorer solutions

Comment: I wouldn't be asking if I wasn't stuck on it for few hours now, any help in the right direction will help tons

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need additional logic (another "AND"). Instead of a "WHERE" clause (which operates before the "GROUP BY") you need [a "HAVING" clause](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp), which operates after the "GROUP BY". Your additional logic can include a subquery to find the size of department 20. Compare that result to each department's size.

```
SELECT DeptId AS "Dept Id", COUNT(EmployeeId) AS "Number of employee"
FROM EMPLOYEE 
GROUP BY DeptId
HAVING
   DeptId <> 20
AND COUNT(EmployeeId) > (SELECT COUNT(EmployeeId) 
                         FROM EMPLOYEE 
                         WHERE DeptId = 20);
```

Comment: I am not allowed to vote (low rep), so it wasn't me, I am testing your solution right now

Comment: It gave me an error 
00934. 00000 -  "group function is not allowed here"

Comment: Hmmm. It is hard to debug without the database. Maybe later I can set up a little sqlite db and try it myself.

Comment: Thanks sir! really appreciate the help, i am working from the sub query you provided.

Comment: `SELECT DeptId as "Dept Id", count(employeeId) as "Number of employee"
FROM EMPLOYEE 
WHERE DeptId IN
 (
   SELECT DeptId
    FROM EMPLOYEE
   GROUP BY DeptId
-- HAVING count(employeeId)>3
 HAVING COUNT(employeeId) > (SELECT COUNT(employeeId) 
                         FROM EMPLOYEE 
                         WHERE DeptId = 20)
  )
AND DeptId <> 20
--AND Count(employeeID) > 4
group by DeptId;`

Comment: Thanks Sir, this way it worked, I just used the sub query you provided inside the other one

Comment: Ok. If you accept the answer, you will get a little reputation. I will update it. Hark! The where clause cannot be used with aggregate functions.

Comment: All done. And learned all about the "HAVING" clause in the process.

Comment: KindaTechy has a slightly superior answer, I will admit. the `deptid <> 20` is superfluous, because department 20 is eliminated from the results by the other part of the HAVING clause (department 20 does not have more members than department 20.)

Answer (score 1):

For ease of explanation, imagine that you have the following `#Employee` table:

```
+ ------ + -------------------- + ------- +
| Emp_Id | Emp_Name             | Dept_Id |
+ ------ + -------------------- + ------- +
| 1      | Jim Ralston          | 6       |
| 2      | Dave Davidson        | 20      |
| 3      | Alexander The Great  | 18      |
| 4      | Tribbidy Trump       | 12      |
| 5      | Anglo Saxon          | 6       |
| 6      | Henry Ford           | 2       |
| 7      | Thomas Eddison       | 9       |
| 8      | Running out of names | 4       |
| 9      | Two More             | 4       |
| 10     | Done!                | 4       |
+ ------ + -------------------- + ------- +
```

Group by Dept_Id and add a having clause that specifies that the count should be greater than the count from Dept 20:

```
select Dept_Id, COUNT(*) as NumberOfEmployees
    from #Employee
    group by Dept_Id
    having COUNT(*) > (
        select COUNT(*)
            from #Employee
            where Dept_Id = 20
    )
```

gives us this table:

```
+ ------- + ----------------- +
| Dept_id | NumberOfEmployees |
+ ------- + ----------------- +
| 4       | 3                 |
| 6       | 2                 |
+ ------- + ----------------- +
```